# Classname not working with {`...${...}...`} or not showing any style in page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying the typical pokedex with the pokeapi and i'm styling it with and for eacht type i wanted to change some styles, mainly colors like background. I created a typesStyles object that has an attribute for each type, and each attribute is an object with properties like:

```
const typesStyles = {
    bug: {
        color: 'lime-800'
    },
// rest of types
}
```

I imported it as typesStyles and wanted to use it in my className's so I did:

```
<div className={`bg-gradient-to-b from-${mainStyles.color} from-50% to-${secondaryStyles.color} to-50% mx-auto flex flex-col p-4 my-4 w-1/2`}>
// ...
</div>
```

Now my problem is that i'm getting no color at all in my localhost for some reason, i put some `onClick={() => console.log(mainStyles.color)}` I get said 'lime-800' in the console. But the weirdest or more frustrating part to me is that when I open the devtools in any browser I do get:

```
<div class="bg-gradient-to-b from-lime-800 from-50% to-lime-800 to-50% mx-auto flex flex-col p-4 my-4 w-1/2">
// ...
</div>
```

And no color at all.

And if I change my code so that it literally says `'...lime-800...'` it works (I don't want that, i want to make it change por each Poke) but when I tried `...${'lime-800'}...`, nothing again. Is it something with react? With tailwind maybe? although I doubt it. I know that typeStyles[bug] returns 'lime-800' via console.log's
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this className={`bg-gradient-to-b from-${mainStyles.color} from-50% to-${secondaryStyles.color} to-50% mx-auto flex flex-col p-4 my-4 w-1/2`}

Answer (score 1):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as *complete unbroken strings* in your source files.
>
> If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS:
>
> **Don’t construct class names dynamically**
>
> ```js
> <div class="text-{{ error ? 'red' : 'green' }}-600"></div>
> ```
>
> In the example above, the strings `text-red-600` and `text-green-600` do not exist, so Tailwind will not generate those classes.
> Instead, make sure any class names you’re using exist in full:
>
> **Always use complete class names**
>
> ```js
> <div class="{{ error ? 'text-red-600' : 'text-green-600' }}"></div>
> ```

You could consider using full class names in definitions, like:

```js
const typesStyles = {
  // …
  bug: {
    color: 'from-lime-800 to-lime-800'
  },
  // …
}:
```

```
<div className={`… ${mainStyles.color} …`}>
```

Or you could look at [configuring `safelist`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) like:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  // …
  safelist: [
    'from-lime-800',
    'to-lime-800',
    // …
  ]
  // …
}
```